# How could I join 4 large tables in BigQuery with Salesforce tables? SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, salesforce, salesforce-communities, salesforce-marketing-cloud

What I want to do is to join each table with the key field `sendID` **which is not unique** (I use the `GROUP BY` function to make it unique)

*FYI: These tables just have information from year 2022.*

I have 4 tables from SalesForce.

- Table 1: salesforce_sent (emails sent to different destinations **and the largest table**)
- Table 2: salesforce_open (destinations which open the email **and it's also a pretty large table**)
- Table 3: salesforce_clicks (destinations which opens the email and clicks the link to a website)
- Table 4: salesforce_sendjobs (Helps to link the information from Salesforce and Google Analytics)

Each table has different columns. I already tried using `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` in my queries but the time running the query it's insane (I've been up to 2-3 hours waiting and then cancel the run).

What I tried is this (I guess using `INNER JOIN` it is better than a `LEFT JOIN` because it's less heavy):

```
WITH SENT AS (
SELECT
  sendid as sendid,
  EXTRACT(date FROM eventdate) as sent_date,
  lower(emailaddress) as emailaddress,
  COUNT(*) as sent,
FROM salesforce_sent
group by 1,2,3
),

CLICKS AS (
SELECT
  sendid as sendid,
  EXTRACT(DATE from eventdate) as click_date,
  url as url,
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_source=([^&]+)') as source,
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_medium=([^&]+)') as medium,
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_campaign=([^&]+)') as campaign,
  regexp_extract(url, r'utm_content=([^&]+)') as ad_content,
  isunique as isunique_click,
  COUNT(*) as clicks,
FROM salesforce_clicks
group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
),

OPEN AS (
SELECT
  sendid as sendid,
  EXTRACT(date FROM eventdate) as open_date,
  isunique as isunique_open,
  COUNT(*) as open
FROM salesforce_opens
group by 1,2,3
),

SENDJOBS AS (
SELECT
  sendid as sendid,
  EXTRACT(date FROM senttime) as sent_date,
  LOWER(emailname) as  emailname,
  LOWER(SPLIT(emailname, '-')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]) AS pos,
FROM salesforce_sendjobs
group by 1,2,3,4
)

SELECT 
  a.sendid as sendid,
  a.sent_date,
  c.open_date,
  d.click_date,
  a.emailaddress,
  b.emailname,
  d.url as url,
  b.pos,
  d.source,
  d.medium,
  d.campaign,
  d.ad_content,
  sum(a.sent) as sent,
  sum(c.open) as open,
  sum(d.clicks) as clicks
FROM SENT a
INNER JOIN SENDJOBS b ON a.sendid = b.sendid
INNER JOIN OPEN c ON a.sendid = c.sendid
INNER JOIN CLICKS d ON a.sendid = d.sendid
WHERE 1=1
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12
```

I also tried using `UNION ALL` but it's not what I'm searching for. Because you won't have the complete information row when it comes to information that you have in table A but not in table B.

What I want is to have a merge between all this 4 tables using the `sendID` as the key. It would be really nice to make lighter the query somehow.  This query process 100 GB when run (is not that much).

I also see that the compute problem it's in the join.

[image]

Comment: There seems to be no join in the code you have provided?

Comment: I would suggest to create the four tables of the CTE (`with` statement) first. Then please check that the field `sendid ` is unique. I doubt that, because you group by other fields such as a date field. If there are several dates to a `sendid`, then `sendid` is not unique. Please use `min` or `any_value`  and only `group by 1`